# How to override ssh port in .kitchen.yml?

Tags: chef

I want to be able to set which port to use for ssh forwarding when running up `kitchen converge`.

I added the `forwarded_port` lines to .kitchen.yml:

```
---                                                                                                                                                        
driver:
  name: vagrant
  network:·
    - ["forwarded_port", {guest: 22, host: 2223}]
```

But `kitchen` still uses the default port for ssh:

```
~/D/octopress git:source ❯❯❯ netstat -n -p tcp | grep 22                                                                                  
....
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.2200         127.0.0.1.59456        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.59456        127.0.0.1.2200         ESTABLISHED
```

Apparently a mapping is created but `kitchen` is not using it.
[image]

I have checked chef website and [this page](https://docs.chef.io/config_yml_kitchen.html) does not provide more in-depth info

How can I override the default ssh port?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give the name of your kitchen instance name, so I will make up a name to proceed with an example.  If, in kitchen, in a cookbook, you created a server called 'default-centos-75', you would edit the following file in the home directory of that cookbook:

`vi .kitchen/default-centos-75.yml`

You would then find the line that begins `port:` and change the port number to your desired port. For instance, change `port: 2222` to `port: 2223`

Comment: This does not work, as kitchen changes the values back to defaults on the next run.

Comment: @ChaimEliyah - You are right it does not survive a kitchen destroy or re-run of kitchen create.  But, it works once you run kitchen create and modify the file as I describe! You CAN re-run kitchen converge over-and-over without losing the settings. Just avoid re-running kitchen create.

Comment: Ah okay. Yes that seems like a good troubleshooting step between runs. I have now forgotten what problem I made the comment for. XD

Comment: This situation occurs when you: 1) create a VM using kitchen; 2) stop the VM without destroying it (e.g. shutdown -h); 3) re-run kitchen create.  If you then want to start the first VM and connect to it using kitchen login command, you have to: 5) change the port mapping for the first VM as you show in the UI, and finally 6) change .kitchen/default-centos-75.yml (or whatever node-name.yml you created with kitchen create) as I show above, matching the updated port mappings you input into the UI